# Programar em C para ARM

Tags: linux, arm, c

Começarei um projeto em C que terá como `target` uma placa [Colibri T20](http://www.toradex.com/products/colibri-arm-computer-modules/colibri-t20), com processador [NVIDIA Tegra 2 ARM](http://www.nvidia.com.br/object/tegra-superchip-br.html), rodando uma versão leve de Linux.

Gostaria de saber se, além de ter que utilizar um compilador cruzado compatível com o processador, eu preciso me preocupar com algum outro detalhe específico da arquitetura ARM.

Pelo que li, parece que a arquitetura do processador só importa se eu estiver programando em Assembly. Estou errado?

Não sei se é relevante, mas meu `host` é Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux).

Comment: Em teoria, você programa para uma maquina abstrata definida pelo C e é trabalho do compilador adaptar o seu código para rodar na arquitetura alvo *como se* ela fosse essa maquina abstrata. A princípio você só deve ter que se preocupar com isso se for usar algum recurso não disponível no C, mas que existe para o seu processador (ex: acessar os pinos de entrada/saída).

Comment: Caso seu projeto for Open Source estaria extremamente interessado em participar :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Você está certo. Minha observação é que há uma ideia errada entre muitos desenvolvedores que portar software em C a uma nova arquitetura é difícil. A menos que se refira ao tipo de programação encontrada em sistemas operacionais, isso simplesmente não é verdade.

O kernel faz boa parte da abstração dos componentes do hardware, tanto que softwares frequentemente pode ser compilados em uma arquitetura e numa outra sem problema. Eu posso pensar em uns exemplos, porém, quando isso não é tão fácil:

- Se o software depende de um outro software proprietário que não pode em si mesmo ser portado. A grande maioria de software em Linux usa bibliotecas que já são de código aberto, então geralmente isso não é uma problema.
- Se o software contém otimizações específicas de uma arquitetura. Um exemplo: A arquitetura x86 tem as extensões MMX e SSE, entre outros, cujo uso específico não pode ser portado diretamente. Enquanto é uma preocupação, isso realmente é raro, porque geralmente o software usa uma biblioteca que utilize essas funcionalidades especiais. Um exemplo seria uma biblioteca que faz processamento de vídeo. No x86 a biblioteca usaria essa extensões, mas no Arm a biblioteca usaria outra extensões que só existem ali. A biblioteca então assume a responsabilidade de portar as implementações a novas arquiteturas, o software que a utilize não precisa preocupar-se a respeito de como.
- Se o software lida diretamente com hardware especifico a uma sistema. Geralmente é o trabalho do kernel fazer isso, porém eu pessoalmente já encontrei software que exige que certos dispositivos estejam disponíveis no sistema, e então o software não se porta muito bem. Geralmente isso pode ser consertado por meio de trocar essa dependência de hardware específico com o uso de uma biblioteca que providencie a mesma funcionalidade nas múltiplas arquiteturas.

Além dessas exceções das quais deve estar ciente, quase todo software em C porta a novas arquiteturas na mesa sistema operacional sem problema porque, como disse o Guilherme no seu comentário, é o trabalho do compilador adaptar o código a forma certa para cada arquitetura, raramente com a intervenção do programador.

Comment: Uma característica muito diferente de ambos os sistemas é a aceleração gráfica. Não sei se Colibri T20 tem aceleração gráfica OpenGLES, mas acredito que sim. O OpenGLES (ES de Embedded System) é diferente do OpenGL tradicional. Uma aplicação baseada em OpenGL certamente é dificilmente portada para ARM, devido ao OpenGLES.

Mas, geralmente, se não há acesso a dispositivos de baixo nível e sempre uso de bibliotecas que existem em ambas as plataformas, o port é feito sem grandes traumas.

Comment: Portar entre Linuxes ou UNIXes, com hardwares completamente diferentes, é tranquilo, desde que o código seja desenvolvido com isto em mente. Por outro lado, portar um código POSIX para um microcontrolador de 16 bits ou outra plataforma diferente de um sistema operacional de uso geral, nunca é simples; não adianta se iludir.

Answer (score 9):

Como dito, em teoria sim, mas na prática é difícil se conseguir essa portabilidade.
Como você esta utilizando um sistema operacional embarcado de larga escala, isso facilita
as coisas, mas isso se torna diferente quando se está utilizando sistemas menos difundidos entre as arquiteturas, ou mesmo nenhum sistema operacional.

Sendo Assembly uma das linguagens de mais baixo nível, você tem grande controle sobre o código gerado, por isso não é incomum usar Assembly *in-line* junto com C por exemplo.

Veja esta citação retirada de http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html

> The problem is exacerbated by the fact that the C Language was not
>   designed for Harvard architectures, it was designed for Von Neumann
>   architectures where code and data exist in the same address space.
>   This means that any compiler for a Harvard architecture processor,
>   like the AVR, has to use other means to operate with separate address
>   spaces.

Tradução livre:

> O problema se torna evidente pelo fato de que a linguagem C não foi
>   projetada para a arquitetura Harvard, ela foi projetada para arquiteturas
>   de Von Neumann na qual código e dados existem no mesmo espaço de endereços.
>   Isso significa que qualquer compilador para arquiteturas Harvard, como o
>   AVR, precisam usar de outros meios para operar com espaços de endereços
>   separados.

Neste caso se utiliza extensões ao standard C para armazenar literais na memória de programa, que em teoria não é o comum em arquiteturas Harvard.

> Pelo que li, parece que a arquitetura do processador só importa se eu
>   estiver programando em Assembly. Estou errado?

Mesmo em Assembly é possível ter um layer de abstração. Ex: Chamando interrupções de software implementadas pelo sistema operacional, de forma que este faça a abstração.

---

<sup>**Nota:** esta resposta não considera o uso de *Linux* como SO, mas sim a portabilidade de uma forma mais abrangente.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Não necessariamente concordando ou discordando dos colegas, eu prefiro ir por outra linha: depende.

Depende do tipo de aplicação que você quer fazer. Essencialmente, como já foi dito, o compilador deve traduzir da linguagem `C` para o conjunto de instruções do *target*, independente da arquitetura utilizada. Se você utiliza compiladores com suporte ao padrão `ANSI C` (como `gcc`), a linguagem `C` em si e as funções `POSIX` poderão ser escritas talvez, sem nenhuma diferença entre as plataformas.

Mas, além do conjunto de instruções, existem outras diferenças entre desktop x86 (que eu estou assumindo que você tem experiência) e uma arquitetura `ARM`. Vou assumir também que em ambos os casos você usa Linux:

- **Hardware embarcado**: O hardware disponível para processamento é mais limitado: você tem menos memória primária e menos "poder de processamento".
- **Consumo de energia**: Dependendo do produto que você vai fazer, deve primar por atender algum requisito de consumo de energia.
- **Periféricos**: Periféricos básicos, como os via USB, devem ser utilizados da mesma forma em ambas as plataformas, já que é função do S.O. e módulos lidar com eles e disponibilizar APIs para o programador. Mas talvez você precise acessar algum outro periférico em um acesso de baixo nível (como utilizando um protocolo SPI ou I2C - o que é muito comum em um sistema embarcado), e isso deve ser diferente em uma plataforma ARM em relação a uma plataforma x86.
- **Aceleração gráfica**: Uma característica muito diferente de um sistema ARM para um PC tradicional é a aceleração gráfica. Geralmente em sistemas ARM só é disponível OpenGLES (ES de Embedded System). O OpenGLES é diferente do OpenGL tradicional. Escrever uma aplicação que utilize aceleração gráfica para ARM é certamente diferente que escrever uma para um PC x86.
- **APIs, bibliotecas e outros softwares**: Você deve estar atento e fazer um levantamento das bibliotecas e softwares externos e APIs que você vai utilizar, e saber se já existem elas para ARM e se elas funcionam corretamente no dispositivo que você vai utilizar.

Em geral, em minha experiência, essas são as características que mais diferenciam os sistemas. A diferença, na minha opinião, vai além do conjunto de instruções dos processadores: ainda que as abstrações de software tentem esconder a arquitetura do sistema e deixar tudo "transparente" para o programador via as mesmas APIs, o "ecossistema" que envolve ARM é diferente do x86. Eu nunca precisei me importar com o conjunto de instruções em si. Se você não necessita fazer uma aplicação ultra-otimizada para essa plataforma, você não deve precisar se importar com o conjunto de instruções também.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

O @AlexandreMarcondes lembrou nos comentários a respeito da *endianess* diferente de ambas as plataformas. Nas palavras dele:

> Tem também a questão do acesso à memória (little endian e big endian), também chamada de endianess. Isso é a ordem que a plataforma (processador) armazena números maiores que 1 byte, se há ou não inversão de ordem

Saber o *endianess* é realmente importante para programação em C principalmente se o programador utiliza `union` em seu código ou se faz transmissão de dados para outros periféricos ou dispositivos pela rede.

Comment: Tem também a questão do acesso à memória (little endian e big endian), também chamada de endianess. Isso é a ordem que a plataforma (processador) armazena números maiores que 1 byte, se há ou não inversão de ordem.

Comment: Bem lembrado! Não sei se posso fazer isso, mas vou atualizar minha resposta com essa informação.

Comment: Eu tentei ser genérico, já que na questão não havia explicação mais detalhada; falei apenas da **possibilidade** de se utilizar aceleração gráfica, já que ele não diz se vai utiliza-la, mas diz utilizar uma placa que atende bons requisitos nesse sentido; acreditei que era um ponto relevante. Além do que, esse é apenas **um** dos pontos citados.

Não entendi sua citação sobre o ATMega48P. O SO é teoricamente responsável por abstrair o acesso ao hardware, mas invariavelmente existem diferenças entre as plataformas (como as que eu citei), mesmo ambas utilizando Linux.

Comment: Acho que li de alguma outra resposta sobre o _footprint_ e acabei misturando no comentario a respeito do ATMega48P. Sobre o SO ter obrigação de ter um HAL, eu acredito que é somente uma função, alguns RTOS não possuem e sua principal característica é justamente o agendamento e _switching_ de _threads_. Mas como sua resposta é voltada ao Linux isso torna-se verdade, em teoria.

Answer (score 2):

Não se esqueça da convenção [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). Por exemplo, na EABI ARM você não manda o `swi [syscall number]`, mas tem que usar o registrador n° 7 para carregar nele o número do *syscall* desejado, enquanto os registradores abaixo deste (`r0` até `r6`) são usados para carregar os argumentos do *syscall*. E finalmente, você só manda o `swi #0`. Exemplo de escrever um output:

```apollo
mov r0, #1 @ stdout, 0 p/ stdin e 2 p/ stderr
ldr r1, = [label da string ascii]
ldr r2, = [label do length da string acima]
mov r7, #4 @ syscall p/ write
swi #0 @ chama o software interrupt
```

Você pode pesquisar mais em PDFs encontrados no site da ARM sobre o ARM EABI e sobre os APCS como [este](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf).

Comment: Bem, eu citei ARM Assembly ali, mas no site da ARM tem muitos E-books abordando até sobre C++, descrições sobre Floating Points (no caso de trabalhos gráficos), etc...

Answer (score 2):

Eu portei recentemente o código de uma aplicacão de linux-x86-i382 para linux-armv8, a dificuldade de portabilidade depende muito da sua aplicacão, no final das contas, o ideal é utilizar interfaces limpas e deixar o código que tem dependencia de arquitetura separado em uma pasta ou um arquivo.

Em geral, as partes de codigo que são mais prováveis de apresentarem erros são partes de IO(arquivos e rede), criptografia e autenticacão(checksum, has, etc).Os principais pontos que geralmente causam problemas são:

- Tamanho dos inteiros: Se você pretende portar seu código para diferentes plataformas, nunca assuma tamanho para inteiros, por exemplo, um pacote definido por:

  ```
  struct packet {
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      int b;
  }
  ```

Terá tamanho diferentes em arquiteturas 64 e 32 bits, o que fará com que, caso essa estrutura seja usada num procolo de rede, os dois computadores não vão conseguir se comunicar. A solucão para isso é usar (c++) ou (c) em que dá para se usar tipos que especificam o tamanho do inteiro: uint8_t, int16_t, etc.

- Endianess: Se for usar tipos que utilizem multiplos bytes, arquiteturas big endian escrevem os bytes na ordem inversa de arquiteturas little endian. É preciso tratar os dois códigos de forma diferentes. Nesse caso, não tem solucão trivial. Uma das formas é tratar todos os bytes de input como bytes simples e recuperar as estruturas de multiplos bytes depois, por exemplo:

  ```
  Little Endian:
  uint32_t a = 0x1234567890,big_a = 0;
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<4,i++)
      big_a += ((a>>(24-8*i))&0xff) << (8*i);
  send(big_a);

  Big Endian:
  a=receive();
  ```

Importante notar que, segundo o [RFC1700](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1700.txt), os bytes devem ser transmitios pela rede de forma Big Endian. Entretanto, caso você esteja implementando seu próprio protocolo, tanto faz, desde que um dos dois lados converta os bytes que recebeu, tem um [artigo da IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/)(em inglês) sobre como lidar com endianess.

Answer (score 1):

Depende da aplicação. 
Se a programação for feita utilizando APIs já disponíveis é bem provável que você não encontre muitos problemas que já foram resolvidos antes. Porém mesmo com APIs se você tiver que lidar com driver de dispositivos é bom conhecer ao menos o endianess já que em C temos os ponteiros para quebrar qualquer regra e sua plataforma tem muitos dispositivos para se preocupar. 
Também é necessário saber o set de instruções que ira usar para informar ao compilador ARM, Thumb, Thumb2.
Seu ARM tem FPU vai habilitar isto?

Também há diversos toolchains disponíveis para ARM. arm-none-eabi (sem suporte a SO, bare-metal), arm-linux-eabi  (Linux), e por ai vai.